# How to use replace(.) in R to replace certain values in a dataframe to NA

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of 600x14 dimensions and I need to use the `replace(.)` command in R to replace certain values in a certain column to `NA`. These values are outliers that I am masking with `NA`. the name of the column is called Response.Size and the name of the dataframe is called `mydata`. The data points of interest I need to replace with NA are in rows 54, 146 and 239 and their corresponding values are 206952, 198146 and 135523 respectively.

This is my first time using R Studio so I am a bit confused. I have tried using the r`eplace(.)` command but can't seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi Isaac! Welcome to StackOverflow. A couple of questions: 1. when you say "their corresponding values are 206952, 198146 and 135523 respectively", what do you mean by that? Are the values in the Response.Size column 206952, 198146 and 135523  or 54, 146 and 239 ?

Comment: Hi Mark. I mean the values are 206952, 198146 and 135523. 54, 146 and 239 are just their points out of 600 (i.e. 206952 is at 54/600 in the dataframe)

Comment: ah cool, 54, 146 and 239 are the row numbers

Comment: 2. are you sure you want to replace outliers with NAs? Generally speaking removing outliers from your data (unless they genuinely were just incorrect measurements) is frowned upon in statistics

Comment: Rather than tell us your data, show us with a `dput` sample. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451).

Comment: I'm just following my assignment instructions haha. I know it is probably not best practice. The answer below from jay.sf solved my question. Thanks for helping though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
> df
  X1     X2 X3
1  0      0  0
2  0      0  0
3  0 206952  0
4  0      0  0
5  0 198146  0
6  0      0  0
7  0 135523  0
> df$X2 <- replace(x=df$X2, list=df$X2 %in% c(206952, 198146, 135523), values=NA)
> df
  X1 X2 X3
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
3  0 NA  0
4  0  0  0
5  0 NA  0
6  0  0  0
7  0 NA  0
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2 = c(0, 0, 206952, 
0, 198146, 0, 135523), X3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is clunky since it requires you to manually enter the items to replace.  Maybe instead  `list = df$X2 < max_not_outlier`  would be more general.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You are right for the case when you want to remove outliers below a certain threshold, but it was asked about how to "replace certain values" in a data frame.

Comment: @jay.sf  Understood, but I find it disappointing when folks answer exactly what's asked instead of answering what really **should** have been asked.  :-(

Comment: @CarlWitthoft OP might have a vector of outliers, e.g. from `boxplot(df$X2)$out,` and first calculating min and max from that is what I would consider clunky. BTW, `replace(x, x < outlier_min | x > outlier_max, NA_real_)` would be the correct solution for that what you have in mind, but that isn't suitable here, because `outlier_min != min(outlier_vec)` and  `outlier_max != max(outlier_vec)`.

Answer (score 1):

There already is an accepted answer but here is another base R one but, though the question specifically asks for a `replace` solution, this is a solution with [`is.na<-`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/NA.html). The function's RHS is a suitable index vector, in this case the logical vector returned by `%in%`.

The data comes from [jay.sf's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76746594/8245406)

```r
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     X2 = c(0, 0, 206952, 0, 198146, 0, 135523), 
                     X3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

is.na(df$X2) <- df$X2 %in% c(206952, 198146, 135523)
df
#>   X1 X2 X3
#> 1  0  0  0
#> 2  0  0  0
#> 3  0 NA  0
#> 4  0  0  0
#> 5  0 NA  0
#> 6  0  0  0
#> 7  0 NA  0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Same comment as for jay.sf 's answer:  should be more general.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, I agree but the question doesn't have test data. I don't believe that all other values are zero, there's no way we can write code to get `max_not_outlier`.

Comment: Of course we can.  First we pick a "figure of merit" such as 3 * sigma  and then reject values greater than that.